# Codeigniter call to Member function Error

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, syntax-error

Hi all I am having an error and I just can't see why codeigniter is throwing the error:

controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Management extends CI_Controller {

    public function index(){
        //calls login page view
        $this->managementView();
    }

    public function managementView(){
        //loads course page view
        $users['users'] = $this->management_model->getInfo();
        $this->load->view("header");
        $this->load->view("users", $users);
        $this->load->view("footer");
    }




}
```

Model:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Management_model extends CI_Model{

    function getInfo(){
        $query = $this->db->get("users"); 
        $result = $query->result_array();
        return $result;
    }

}
```

I am receiving the following error, I just can't seem to see what the hell I'm doing wrong - I'm new to web stuff so don't know what these errors indicate:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getInfo() on a non-object
```

also see this:

```
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Management::$management_model

Filename: controllers/management.php

Line Number: 12
```

I can't see the issue? - If anyone could point it out would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to load the model before calling any function from the model.
for eg:

```
$this->load->model('management_model');
$users['users'] = $this->management_model->getInfo();
```

or you can load it via the constructor.

```
function __construct() {
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->model('management_model');
  }
}
```

the notice you are getting is clearly telling about the undefined property management model
you can see more about this [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html)

Answer (score 1):

You dont appear to ever set the management_model property in your controller.

I would expect to see something like this somewhere in your controller:

```
$this->management_model = new Management_model();
```

Answer (score 0):

Initially you can load the model like this

```
$this->load->model('management_model');
```

then only u can use the object to call function

you need some more clarity [Click](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html)

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$this->load->model('management_model');
```

before

```
$users['users'] = $this->management_model->getInfo();
```